# Развернуть слово

Tags: строки, char

Надо развернуть слова наоборот, чтобы при этом небуквенные символы оставались на своих местах.

Например:
**a1bcd => d1cba**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Заводим указатели на начало и конец строки, идем в цикле, первый указатель увеличиваем, второй уменьшаем, цифры проскакиваем. Меняем между собой буквы на которые смотрят указатели. Завершаемся, когда указатели сравнялись.

В виде кода как то так (правда вы язык не указали):

```
int j = 0;
int k = ch.length-1;
while(j<k) {
 char tmp;
      if(! Character.isLetter(ch[j])) j++;
 else if(! Character.isLetter(ch[k])) k--;
 else
  {
   tmp=ch[j]; ch[j]=ch[k]; ch[k]=tmp;
   j++; k--;
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, это то, что надо было.

Comment: @fill Ну, коль то, то поддержи автора, отметив ответ как правильный, нажав на зеленую галочку

Answer (score 4):

```
var s = "a1bcd";
var rev = s.match(/[a-z]/gi).reverse(), i = 0;
var res = s.replace(/[a-z]/gi, m => rev[i++]);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 3):

На C#:

```
public string ReverseSkippingNonLetters(String source)
{
    var result = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
    {
        Char
            forward = source[i],
            backward = source[source.Length - i - 1];

        if(!Char.IsLetter(forward))
            result.Append(forward);

        if(Char.IsLetter(backward))
            result.Append(backward);
    }

    return result.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ну, вот развертка слова наоборот вручную без использования доп.методов с сортировкой, вдруг понадобится

```
private char[] SortArray(char[] arr) {
     char max = arr[0];
     for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++ {
         max = arr[i];
         for (int j = i; j < arr.Length; j++) {
             if (max < arr[j]) {
                max = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = max;
             }
             else if (max>='0'&&max<='9') {
                arr[i] = max;
                break;
             }
         }
     }
     return arr; 
}
```

Comment: В вопросе про сортировку ни слова нет

Comment: @Mike а даже так, я прост на пример посмотрел, додумал, что нужна еще и сортировка)

Answer (score 2):

Решение на *C++11* с использованием *STL*:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

std::string specReverse(const std::string& str)
{
    std::string result(str);

    for (auto begin = result.begin(), end = result.end() - 1; begin < end; )
    {
        if (!isalpha(*begin))
            ++begin;
        else if (!isalpha(*end))
            --end;
        else
            std::swap(*begin++, *end--);
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    const std::string input = "a1bcd";
    std::cout << "Input=\"" << input << 
              "\", output=\"" << specReverse(input) << "\"." << std::endl;
}
```